# Fastest way to encode characters in a list of list of strings

Tags: python, nlp

For an NLP task, given a mapping, I need to encode each unicode character to an integer in a list of list of words. I'm trying to figure out a quick way to do this without dropping down into cython.

Here's a slowish way to write the function:

```
def encode(sentences, mappings):
    encoded_sentences = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        encoded_sentence = []
        for word in sentence:
            encoded_word = []
            for ch in word:
                encoded_word.append(mappings[ch])
            encoded_sentence.append(encoded_word)
        encoded_sentences.append(encoded_sentence)
    return encoded_sentences
```

Given the following input data:

```
my_sentences = [['i', 'need', 'to'],
            ['tend', 'to', 'tin']]

mappings = {'i': 0, 'n': 1, 'e': 2, 'd':3, 't':4, 'o':5}
```

I want `encode(my_sentences, mappings)` to produce:

```
[[[0], [1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 5], [4, 0, 1]]]
```

Comment: Probably not much faster ways of doing it in Python. You could try using `str.translate` and to the `str` representation of the numbers, then `list(map(int, word))`, but that might only be slightly faster if you were dealing with long words...

Comment: And, having done a couple quit `timeit`s, a comprehension approach is not really working faster, actually, significantly slower (which is surprising), and the explicit for-loops are winning out.

Answer (score 3):

**List comprehensions** are 23% faster (and more concise):

```
%%timeit
encode(my_sentences, mappings)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.75 µs per loop

def encode_compr(sentences, mappings):
    return [[[mappings[char] for char in word] for word in sent] for sent in sentences]

%%timeit
encode_compr(my_sentences, mappings)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.67 µs per loop
```

#### Slower alternatives (for the record)

*string.translate*

```
import string
_from = 'inedto'
_to = '012345'
trans = string.maketrans(_from, _to)

def encode_translate(sentences, mappings):
    return [[[int(string.translate(char, trans)) for char in word] for word in sent] for sent in sentences]    

%%timeit
encode_translate(my_sentences, mappings)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.4 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can gain something from `str.translate` (Py2) or `bytes.translate` (Py3) if you use it for bulk conversions, avoiding working with heavyweight individual `int` values, instead doing C level transformations. The end result isn't a `list` of `list`s though, it's a `list` of `bytearray` (or `bytes` on Py3); for a collection of small `int` values (from 0 to 255) `bytearray` is largely equivalent (it's a mutable sequence, just like `list`) so it's often all you need. First, outside the function, you make a translation table:

```
# Py2
import string
transtable = string.maketrans('inedto', str(bytearray(range(6))))

# Py3
transtable = bytes.maketrans(b'inedto', bytes(range(6)))
```

Then use it in the function:

```
# Py2
def encode(sentences, mappings):
    return [[bytearray(w).translate(mappings) for w in sentence]
            for sentence in sentences]

# Py3
def encode(sentences, mappings):
    # Assumes sentences are bytes, not str; can be tweaked to work with str
    # but it will be slower/more complicated
    return [[w.translate(mappings) for w in sentence]
            for sentence in sentences]
```

Timings on Py2 achieve results in ~2/3rds the time of the original:

```
>>> %timeit -r5 encode(my_sentences, mapping)  # Original function
100000 loops, best of 5: 4.51 µs per loop
>>> %timeit -r5 encode(my_sentences, transtable)  # My alternate function
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.97 µs per loop
```

Py3 improvements are similar, but only if the input sentences are `bytes` objects, not `str` (and therefore avoid extra conversions). It all depends on what you can live with on input and output format.